# How to reproduce this distortion/bending in C4D?

Tags: 3d, cinema-4d

I’m trying to bend a ring like this but don’t manage to do it... But it looks so simple :(

[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: one quick'n'dirty option is to use two lathes/lofts one that is 75% of the right, the other the remaining 25% (just eyeballing the lenght of the twist). To the shorter section apply a twist deformer. There might be eitherways too, but unless you're looking for a programming related solution, this isn't the best place to ask this as it's off-topic.

Comment: Hey @GeorgeProfenza thanks for your answer. Where to ask then if not here?

Comment: Unfortunately the [3D Graphics Stackexchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86368/3d-graphics) isn't ready yet, but you can commit to it and contribute with questions like this one.
What you can use at the moment is existing C4D forums (such as [C4D Cafe](http://www.c4dcafe.com/ipb/forums/), [CG Society](http://forums.cgsociety.org/forumdisplay.php?f=47), etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a setup like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6U6B.jpg). Which gives you the freedom to animate all parameters as well for more flexibility.

As mentioned by George, maybe post future C4D questions on [C4D Cafe](https://www.c4dcafe.com/ipb/)

Comment: That looks nice but I could not reproduce it. Please give more Information on how you actually did it. I have the exact same setup (apparently not) and it does no look like yours, not at all. The cube does not take the full circle size. Please let me know your settings. Here is my result: http://imgur.com/a/PvrG1

Comment: and this is what I get when I increase the length of the cube: http://imgur.com/a/PvrG1

Comment: Thanks I got it working, had to play around with the Rotation values of the spline wrap!